# How To Refresh Google Map In Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

I need to refresh google map every time I press the "show" button that changes the lat and lng.

I'm using AGM for the Google Map.

Here I'm getting the lat and lng I wanna see on the map:

```
onShow(_token: string) {
        var find = this.model.find(({ token }) => token === _token);

        this.postsService.setLat(find.lat);
        this.postsService.setLng(find.lng);

        console.log(
            this.postsService.getLat() + '    ' + this.postsService.getLng()
        );
    }
```

On the web page i have some locations. When I press "Show" button I want to see that location I point to on the map.

That's app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PostsService } from './posts.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(public postsService: PostsService) {}

    title = 'Location Project';
    lat: number = this.postsService.getLat();
    lng: number = this.postsService.getLng();
    zoom: number = 12;
}
```

The problem is that the map is created with lat and lng being undefined (and so the map shows a default point in the ocean). How can i refresh the map every time I change the lat and lng values?

app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header> <br /><br />

<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>

<br /><br />

<app-post-list></app-post-list>
```

posts.service:

```
import { Location } from './post.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, Subscription, from } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PostsService {
    model: Location[] = [];

    constructor() {}

    private lat;
    private lng;

    setLat(lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    setLng(lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
    getLat() {
        return this.lat;
    }
    getLng() {
        return this.lng;
    }
}
```

[Here's a screenshot of some hardcoded lat and lng values, to show how it should appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP8hJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Where are the map markers set? You must define markers with the new locations and set them on the map. I think you're showing lat and lng variables, but you're not setting them in your onShow method. You only call setLat, setLng method from the service but not updating the lat and lng variables!

Comment: I don't set the markers neither initialize the map, that's Angular's job. See the original post, I attached a photo with some hardcoded lat and lng.

Comment: by the way, I'm using AGM.

Comment: I don't know what AGM is. Can you share your html and PostsService too? I've developed apps using Google Maps Javascript API and Angularjs. I don't think that Google Maps API usage will change too much with Angular?

Comment: I'm adding these into the original post in a minute.

Comment: Also, that's AGM: https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Well not enough documentation on AGM guides. I think check out Google Maps Javascript API and use it. You'll both understand the mechanism and will be able to do whatever customization you want. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview

Comment: I will replace the AGM with the Google Maps JS Api, the documentation seems more clear. Thank you sir!